# How to achieve this grid layout?

Tags: html, css

I want to have  a layout like

[image]

But I'm not achieving the title 6 and title 7. Do you know what is necessary to add that divs to the layout?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/re221faf/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="title_1">
    <h6>Title 1</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="title_2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title_3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="title_4">Title 4 </div>
  <div class="title_5">Title 5</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {border:5px solid gray;}
.title_1{border-bottom:5px solid gray;}
.title_2{float:left; padding: 20px 0;}
.title_3{float:right; padding: 20px 0;}

.clear{clear:both;}

.title_4{border-top:5px solid gray; border-bottom: 5px solid gray;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into CSS Grid

1. [A complete guide to CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
2. [A nice game to understand CSS Grid](https://cssgridgarden.com/#fr)

A working snippet with comments :

```css
.card{
   /* create a css grid */
   display:grid;
   /* create 4 rows, the first two take up two fractions, and the last two take up 1 fraction */
   grid-template-rows: 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
   /* create 3 columns of specified sizes */
   grid-template-columns: 45% 45% 10%;
}

.card > div{
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align:center;
}


.title_1{
   /* element starts on the first column line and ends on the third*/
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   /* element starts on the first row line and spans one row */
   grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}
.title_2{
   grid-column: 1 / 2;
   grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}
.title_3{
   grid-column: 2 / 3;
   grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}
.title_4{
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 3 / span 1;
}
.title_5{
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 4 / span 1;
}
.title_6{
   grid-column: 3 / 4;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.title_7{
   grid-column: 3 / 4;
   grid-row: 2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="title_1">
    <h6>Title 1</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="title_2">Title 2</div>
  <div class="title_3">Title 3</div>
  <div class="title_4">Title 4 </div>
  <div class="title_5">Title 5</div>
  <div class="title_6">Title 6</div>
  <div class="title_7">Title 7</div>
</div>
```